# Launch Oozie job with custom spark version

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to run a Spark job via oozie on my HDP 2.6.1 cluster. The Spark versions initially installed are 1.6.1 and 2.1.1. I added the 2.3.0 pre-built package (Hadoop 2.7 and later) version via sharelibupdate (by creating a directory in which I copied all spark 2.3.0 jars + Oozie jar) but am facing this error : `..././assembly/target/scala-2.11/jars' does not exist; make sure Spark is built.`

I am runing spark in Spark cluster mode.

Did anyone ever face this problem ? Is it even possible to add a spark version like this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. It is related to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2606) `Oozie` known problem. I simply had to add a spark property `spark.yarn.jars` with the path to spark 2.3.0 jars